# How can I prevent widgets to go outside Window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am doing a tasks and I have one problem over and over again. My widgets(buttons mostly) can't leave a window and they do. For an example I have on task where I need to move button over a window by using arrow keys. My button shouldn't leave window but it does. How I can prevent it from doing this?

I tried to set pixel border like this:

```
x = int(button.place_info()['x'])
    if x < 236:
        if event:
            button.place(x=x + 5)
```

But when you make a window bigger(by maximizing) it won't get to an edge and it has to.

```
import tkinter as tk


def exit(event):
    if event:
        window.destroy()


def up(event):
    y = int(button.place_info()['y'])
    if event:
        button.place(y=y - 1)


def down(event):
    y = int(button.place_info()['y'])
    if event:
        button.place(y=y + 1)


def left(event):
    x = int(button.place_info()['x'])
    if event:
        button.place(x=x - 1)
        print(x)


def right(event):
    x = int(button.place_info()['x'])
    if x < 236:
        if event:
            button.place(x=x + 1)




window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
button = tk.Button(master=window, bitmap="questhead")
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center", )
button.focus_set()
button.bind("<Up>", up)
button.bind("<Down>", down)
button.bind("<Left>", left)
button.bind("<Right>", right)


window.bind("<Escape>", exit)

window.mainloop()
```

Is there any default function or something I can use to make window has borders that widget can't cross and just disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` methods to get the current height/width of a window. Once you have these, you can use these values to `bind` the moving widget inside the window.

I've also used these methods to centre the widget in the screen when it opens rather than the `rely` and `relx` that you had used.

Note that for each button press method, I am performing a check to see if the widget is still inside the window with either >0 or

```
import tkinter as tk


def exit(event):
    if event:
        window.destroy()


def up(event):
    y = int(button.place_info()['y'])
    if y > 0:
        if event:
            button.place(y=y - 5)


def down(event):
    widget_h = event.widget.master.winfo_height()
    y = int(button.place_info()['y'])
    if y < widget_h:
        if event:
            button.place(y=y + 5)


def left(event):
    x = int(button.place_info()['x'])
    if x > 0:
        if event:
            button.place(x=x - 5)
            print(x)


def right(event):
    widget_w = event.widget.master.winfo_width()
    x = int(button.place_info()['x'])
    if x < widget_w:
        if event:
            button.place(x=x + 5)




window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.update()
x_mid = window.winfo_width()//2
y_mid = window.winfo_height()//2
print(x_mid,y_mid)
button = tk.Button(master=window, bitmap="questhead")
button.place(x=x_mid, y=y_mid, anchor="center", )
button.focus_set()
button.bind("<Up>", up)
button.bind("<Down>", down)
button.bind("<Left>", left)
button.bind("<Right>", right)


window.bind("<Escape>", exit)

window.mainloop()
```